# passing functions to functions in matlab / octave

Tags: matlab, octave

I'm looking at passing a function to a function.

what I want to do is create a finite difference based function to which I can pass different function to be differentiated.

For example:

```
function ybar = diff_finite ( x , h , function_inquestion) 
  ybar = ((function_inquestion(x+h) - function_inquestion(x)) / h
end
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [function handles](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function_handle.html).